# create a list of all files from a directory in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I need to make an excel sheet of all the files in a directory, specifically image files, html and css files. I would also need to get the title of the html page that is between the `<title></title>`

Is this possible within excel? Perhaps using macros/vb?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can do it using VBA. Look at `Dir()` for the file listing

Comment: @TimWilliams And how can I do set the path to the Dir to list?

Comment: You'd read the examples for `Dir()` and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Query to quickly create a list of all files in a file share, including sub-folders, and then filter for specific file types.

Power Query is a free download from Microsoft and works with Professional Plus editions of Excel 2010 and 2013. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379

If you don't have the Professional Plus license, you can use VBA. See [my blog post with sample file and code to list files and folders in Excel](http://www.teylyn.com/list-all-files-in-folder-to-excel/). You can turn the result into an Excel table with a click on Insert ribbon > Table and filter the file type.